# Fixing "State for CSRF is not correct" with Python flask-awscognito and boto3/request

Tags: flask, jwt, boto3, csrf, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use flask-awscognito to create a simple example server and client that authenticates with AWS Cognito but I am getting an error that I cannot find documentation on how to fix.

The server is crashing with this error:

```
flask_awscognito.exceptions.FlaskAWSCognitoError: State for CSRF is not correct
```

This is the server code:

```
from flask import request, jsonify
import flask.json
from flask_awscognito import AWSCognitoAuthentication

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

app.config['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = '...' # from the user pool console page
app.config['AWS_COGNITO_DOMAIN'] = '...' # just used the domain name of eventual app's domain here but I don't know if it's associate with the pool in any way. This might as well be a random string.
app.config['AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID'] = '...' # from the user pool console page
app.config['AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID'] = '...' # from the user pool console page
app.config['AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET'] = '' # from the user pool console page
app.config['AWS_COGNITO_REDIRECT_URL'] = 'http://localhost:5000/aws_cognito_redirect' # left this from the docs but not sure what I'll have it as in the future.

aws_auth = AWSCognitoAuthentication(app)

@app.route("/auth_test")
@aws_auth.authentication_required
def auth_test ():
    print (request.args)
    return jsonify({
        "claims" : aws_auth.claims,
        "token" : aws_auth.get_access_token(request.args)
    })

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the client code:

```
import requests
import boto3

host = "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
region = '...' # same as in server
user_pool_id = '...' # same as in server
username = '...' # a user that is in the pool
password = '...' # correct password from the pool
app_client_id = '...' # same as in server
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name = region)
route = "/auth_test"

auth_response = client.admin_initiate_auth(
    UserPoolId = user_pool_id,
    ClientId = app_client_id,
    AuthFlow = 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
    AuthParameters = {
        'USERNAME' : username,
        'PASSWORD' : password
    }
)
print (auth_response)
id_token = auth_response['AuthenticationResult']['IdToken']
response = requests.get(host + route , headers = { 'Authorization': "Bearer " + id_token })
print(response.json())
```

Notice I'm not passing `STATE=whatever` in my client as post arg. Not sure what it would be. I have Googled around for whether or not it's included in the auth response I get back. Perhaps that's required. I'm not sure I even need CSRF in my single page app with Cognito managing sessions. I'm fine disabling the server needing it or including in all clients that send the data. I just want it to work properly.

Anyone know how to fix this error? Thank you!

I've attempted to add add the following lines after Googling around for similar problems and it did not change the error message.

```
from flask_cors import CORS
CORS(app)
```

Comment: In my case the config values were set to localhost but in the browser I was using 127.0.0.1 which caused this mismatch

Answer (score 1):

The correct value of `state` needs to be generated on flask server-side, and passed to AWS Cognito and then back.

You need to configure both `app.config['AWS_COGNITO_DOMAIN']` and `app.config['AWS_COGNITO_REDIRECT_URL']` and then you can use `aws_auth.get_sign_in_url()` to generate url to AWS Cognito with proper `state` value. For example:

```
@app.route('/sign_in')
def sign_in():
    return redirect(aws_auth.get_sign_in_url())
```

See [this example](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-AWSCognito/).